Node js asynchron router
i have a question about Node js router, i want that the router send a answer for the webrequest directly without waiting for some code which is inside a promise block and i am not sure if i have understand asynchron working from nodejs good enough, if my following code would do that:
    let objektKunden=[];
app.get('/getuser', async function (req, res)
{
  try
  {
     new Promise((resolve) => {
      //console.log(getuser);
      
      const kundenData = [];
      const masterData = [];

        Kunden.forEach(item => {
          if (item.note !== "master") {
            kundenData.push(item);
          } else {
            masterData.push(item);
          }
        });
      objektKunden[0]=kundenData;
      objektKunden[1]=APIKeyInvalid;
      objektKunden[2]=Masteraccounts;
      objektKunden[3]=masterData;
      const responseJSON = JSON.stringify(objektKunden);     
  });
  res.status(200).json(objektKunden);
  }
  catch (error)
  {
    console.error("error getuser:", error);
    res.status(500).send("error");
  }
});

What i want is that the router send objektKunden directly as answer and dont wait that the code above which is inside the promise will be run first

your promise doesn't do anything, all the code is synchronous.

You never use await, there's no point in declaring the function async.

If you don't wait for the code inside the promise, objektKunden will not be filled in and you'll send an empty array in the JSON response. So what you want doesn't make sense: you can't send the data generated by a function without waiting for it.

@Barmar, the objektKunden is a global object it does not lose his data and when for example every second my websie does call this router it will be filled after the seonds request. but i am just not sure how to make this so that the pomise code will run asynchron in background and the router "getuser" must send always directly the objektKunden data

So each request will return the data generated by the previous request? Why do you even need the requests to uipdate the object? Use setInterval() to update the object periodically, and the request can just return the latest value.
